# Ada interfaces with Cobol

Tags: ada, cobol

I am studying the Ada-> Cobol interface, and am wondering if there is any way to write the files to cobol default, without having to have a Cobol code written too, because I want to write a file using some rules of COBOL, but would to know how to do this directly in Ada.

For example, to read a file with cobol structure, I can use use that way:

```
with Interfaces.COBOL;
with COBOL_Sequential_IO; -- Assumed to be supplied by implementation
procedure Test_External_Formats is
112
   -- Using data created by a COBOL program
   -- Assume that a COBOL program has created a sequential file with
   --  the following record structure, and that we need to
   --  process the records in an Ada program
   --  01 EMPLOYEE-RECORD
   --     05 NAME    PIC X(20).
   --     05 SSN     PIC X(9).
   --     05 SALARY  PIC 99999V99 USAGE COMP.
   --     05 ADJUST  PIC S999V999 SIGN LEADING SEPARATE.
   -- The COMP data is binary (32 bits), high-order byte first
113
   package COBOL renames Interfaces.COBOL;
114
   type Salary_Type      is delta 0.01  digits 7;
   type Adjustments_Type is delta 0.001 digits 6;
115
   type COBOL_Employee_Record_Type is  -- External representation
      record
         Name    : COBOL.Alphanumeric(1..20);
         SSN     : COBOL.Alphanumeric(1..9);
         Salary  : COBOL.Byte_Array(1..4);
         Adjust  : COBOL.Numeric(1..7);  -- Sign and 6 digits
      end record;
   pragma Convention (COBOL, COBOL_Employee_Record_Type);
116
   package COBOL_Employee_IO is
      new COBOL_Sequential_IO(COBOL_Employee_Record_Type);
   use COBOL_Employee_IO;
117
   COBOL_File : File_Type;
118
   type Ada_Employee_Record_Type is  -- Internal representation
      record
         Name    : String(1..20);
         SSN     : String(1..9);
         Salary  : Salary_Type;
         Adjust  : Adjustments_Type;
      end record;
119
   COBOL_Record : COBOL_Employee_Record_Type;
   Ada_Record   : Ada_Employee_Record_Type;
120
   package Salary_Conversions is
      new COBOL.Decimal_Conversions(Salary_Type);
   use Salary_Conversions;
121
   package Adjustments_Conversions is
      new COBOL.Decimal_Conversions(Adjustments_Type);
   use Adjustments_Conversions;
122
begin
   Open (COBOL_File, Name => "Some_File");
123
   loop
     Read (COBOL_File, COBOL_Record);
124
     Ada_Record.Name := To_Ada(COBOL_Record.Name);
     Ada_Record.SSN  := To_Ada(COBOL_Record.SSN);
     Ada_Record.Salary :=
        To_Decimal(COBOL_Record.Salary, COBOL.High_Order_First);
     Ada_Record.Adjust :=
        To_Decimal(COBOL_Record.Adjust, COBOL.Leading_Separate);
     ... -- Process Ada_Record
   end loop;
exception
   when End_Error => ...
end Test_External_Formats;
```

Put, I don't know how to write a File with cobol structure, in the documentation, I not find a way; http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/~andy/lrm95/b_04.htm

For example, if I have that struct in Cobol ( based on this sample: http://www.csis.ul.ie/cobol/examples/Sort/MaleSort.htm ; http://www.csis.ul.ie/cobol/examples/SeqIns/STUDENTS.DAT )

```
FILE SECTION.
FD StudentFile.
01 StudentRec      PIC X(30).
   88 EndOfFile    VALUE HIGH-VALUES.

FD MaleStudentFile.
01 MaleStudentRec  PIC X(30).

SD WorkFile.
01 WorkRec.
   02 FILLER             PIC 9(7).
   02 WStudentName       PIC X(10).
   02 FILLER             PIC X(12).
   02 WGender            PIC X.
      88 MaleStudent     VALUE "M".
```

How I can make a program to write this struct, in Ada, using Cobol interfaces ?

Comment: If you can READ a file that way, have you tried to WRITE in a similar manner?

Answer (score 2):

Think physically.  That is, what is the output file's format?  Whether you create that file in  Cobol or Ada is NOT an immediate issue when designing a file.

Let's assume that Cobol Workrec describes your file's format. Do you want to write an Ada program that calls a cobol subroutine to physically write the file? or do you want to use a Cobol program to write the file?  Or do you want an Ada program that writes a file in the smae format as Workrec??  Your choice depends on your customer's requirements.